# Changing layout to fixed, centered while adjusting footer to stick to bottom

Tags: css, html, layout, sticky-footer

Well, I am very new and learning as I go here, so code has been added throughout this process and may be bloated and redundantly redundant.

I am trying to style my site so that everything remains centered in the page. I originally had this done and looking how I wanted but realized that everything was in a fluid layout. I want the information to remain fixed and simply have the background color extend fluidly to the right and left as needed for larger screens.

I have managed to adjust the header to a fixed layout into the center but now the white border will not extend out to either side to fill the rest of the header space. I was able to do this in a fluid layout but cannot figure out how to accomplish this now.

I am in the process of trying to convert the body and footer over as well. Currently the footer is coded following a sticky footer code I found while researching, however as mentioned above it was fluid and adjusting the browser size resulted my text moving when decreasing the size horizontally and the footer sliding in behind the body when changing the vertical size of the browser. I want to create a fixed, centered footer that remains at the bottom of the page with the black background extending out to the right and left fluidly to fill in the space.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

HTML:

```
<div id="page">

<div id="header">


</div>


<div id="main">

</div>

<div id="footer">
   <div class="footer-info">
  <ul>
         <li><p><strong>Address </strong> <br>
 Street<br>
 City, state, zip​<br>
 phone</p></li>
         <li><p><strong>Address </strong> <br>
 Street<br>
 City, state, zip​<br>
 phone</p></li>
         <li><p><strong>Address </strong> <br>
 Street<br>
 City, state, zip​<br>
 phone</p></li>
         <li><p>​© 2013​</p></li>
      </ul>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";


#header {
font: 100%/1.4 Open Sans, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
color: #7C0408;
width:1000px;
text-align:center;
}


body {
font: 100%/1.4 Open Sans, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #eae5e5;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
Height: 100%;
color: #000;
}


/*     BEGIN FOOTER     */


.footer-info li {
color: white;
background-color: black;
list-style-type:none;
margin: 0;
padding-left:10px;
display:inline-block;
}

.footer-info li:nth-child(4) {
font-size: 0.8em;
vertical-align:250%;
}

#footer {
Position: absolute;
Width: 100%;
Bottom: 0;
Height: 75px;  /* This value is the height of your footer */
font: 75%/1.4 Open Sans, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: black;
padding: 10px 0px 12px 0px;
text-align:center;
color: white;
}


/*     END FOOTER     */


Html {
Padding: 0;
Margin: 0;
Height: 100%;
}


#page {
Min-height: 100%;  /* for all other browsers */
height: 100%;  /* for IE */
position:relative;
}


#main {
Padding-bottom: 75px;   /* This value is the height of your footer */
}



/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { 
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
margin-top: 0;   
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px; 
}





/* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  
float: right;
margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { 
float: left;
margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { 
clear:both;
height:0;
font-size: 1px;
line-height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: If your question is simply "how do I create a fixed, centered, footer" please show only the HTML and CSS that have to do with the question. Oh, and you could make the question itself shorter too.

Comment: I guess I had a couple questions in my rambling. Let's start with how do I create a fixed, centered footer that will stay at the bottom of the page while allowing the background color to extend out fluidly to either side of the page? I have been able to do both. Will update the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I used the HTML code that you supplied to answer, but I really would recommend trying to indent better and try to find a way to get around having to use `<br>` tags. I rewrote the CSS, because it was just easier to start from scratch.

I created a jsfiddle for you and annotated it so you can understand what is happening with the CSS. To get the look you want, the header and footer will still be fluid (width wise), but the text/logo inside of them will be fixed by using CSS to make sure they are placed in the center. There's multiple ways to do the header, some without using the extra `<div>`, but there wasn't really any information on what would go there. You'll also need to create a new division to hold everything but the footer so that it scales correctly to your page's height.

http://jsfiddle.net/kHBC8/

I would really recommend taking a look at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ It does a really great job of explaining how to get a sticky footer like you want and will be a valuable resource as you continue to learn.